# Integration sampled data in R

Tags: r, integration, interpolation, measurement

I have some measuring data sampled over time and want to integrate it, the [test dataset](http://tux4u.de/so.rtab.gz) contains ~100000 samples (~100s, 1000Hz) of data.

My first approach was (`table` contains the timestamp (0..100s) and the value of each data point (both `double`s))

```
# test dataset available (gzipped, 720k) here: http://tux4u.de/so.rtab.gz
table <- read.table("/tmp/so.rtab", header=TRUE)
time <- table$t
data <- table$val
start <- min(time)
stop <- max(time)
sampling_rate <- 1000
divs <- (max(time) - min(time)) * sampling_rate
data_fun <- approxfun(time, data, method="linear", 0, 0)
result <- integrate(data_fun, start, stop, subdivisions=divs)
```

but somehow the integration runs forever (like an endless loop and eats up one CPU completely). So I looked at the values:

```
> start
[1] 0
> stop
[1] 98.99908
> divs
[1] 98999.08
```

The strange thing is that when I evaluate

```
> integrate(data_fun, 0, 98, subdivisions=100000)$value + integrate(data_fun, 98, 99)$value
[1] 2.640055
```

it works (computation time <3s) but the following evaluation (should be the same)

```
> integrate(data_fun, 0, 99, subdivisions=100000)$value
```

never terminates, too. And even this one (which is in fact a SUBintegral of the one working above) does NOT terminate:

```
> integrate(data_fun, 0, 89, subdivisions=100000)$value
```

It seems a bit random to me when it works and when it doesn't. Am I doing anything wrong or could I improve the process somehow?

Thanks!

(HINT: *the sampling points are not necessarily distributed equally*)

Comment: integrate() makes some effort to see where the function goes to zero. Erratic results have been reported before. In the details section you read: "Like all numerical integration routines, these evaluate the function on a finite set of points. If the function is approximately constant (in particular, zero) over nearly all its range it is possible that the result and error estimate may be seriously wrong."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ekhem, you know that you may just sum it up? `cumsum` will do this fast:

```
cumsum(table$val)*diff(table$t)[1]
```

For unequal differences, you may use:

```
cumsum(table$val[-nrow(table)]*diff(table$t))
```

There is no need of more complex numerics since the data in this case is very densly sampled; nevertheless there will be always better methods than going through interpolator.

Comment: Which would be the integral only in the case where all the `t`'s had diffs of 1.

Comment: correct, the `cumsum` method only works if all data values are distributed equally. Then you can use `cumsum(table$val[1:length(table$val)-1]) * (table$t[2]-table$t[1])`. Unfortunately my data is not necessarily distributed equally :-(

Comment: @Johannes From what I have seen, they are -- the differences are negligible. Yet I'll upgrade my answer.

Comment: @mbq: right: That dataset should have equally distributed samples. Never the less I cannot assume that and I'd like to have a generic solution. Thanks!